# How do i publish a new article with editing restriction in wikitravelbook.com?

Tags: wiki

Does anybody know how to publish a new article with make it **non-editable** . I tried to submit article with editing restriction but it seems that all of your article can be edited by other users .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any kind of administrative privileges? If so, you should be able to protect the article using the administrative tools. If not, then you probably aren't allowed to make articles read-only with your current permission level.